# Django - not replacing my string as expected

Tags: python, django

I need help I have no clue how to solve it.

I'm working with files. Basically I'm opening a file, reading what's inside it, look for a word and replace the word next to it

I'm opening a text file, in this case I have two words which are called with the same name, they are separated for `PART 1` and `PART 2`

**this is my car.txt**

```
PART 1

car toyota



PART 2

car toyota
```

as you can see I have the same word separated for `part` so my script will look for both and show this in my template..

this is how it's working

**views.py**

```
def car_p1():
    file = open("car.txt","r")
    content = file.read()
    file.close()
    car = re.findall('car\s(.*?)\s',open('car.txt','r').read())
    if car:
        print car
    else:
        print 'no car found!'
    return car[0]


def car_p2():
    file = open("car.txt","r")
    content = file.read()
    file.close()
    car = re.findall('car\s(.*?)\s',open('car.txt','r').read())
    if car:
        print car
    else:
        print 'no car found!'
    return car[1]


def get_items(request):
    car = car_p1()
    car2 = car_p2()
    if 'car' in request.POST:
        car_change(request)
        return redirect('get_items')
    return render(request, 'cars.html', {'car':car, 'car2':car2,})

def car_change(request):
    car = car_p1()
    car2 = car_p2()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        change_car = str(request.POST['car_1'])
        change_car_2 = str(request.POST['car_2'])
        filedata= None
        with open('car.txt', 'r') as f:
            filedata = f.read()
            filedata=filedata.replace(car , change_car , 1)
            filedata=filedata.replace(car2 , change_car_2 , 1)
            with open('car.txt', 'wb') as f:
                f.writelines(filedata)
    return render(request, 'cars.html')
```

Here's my problem. I want to change part 1 from toyota to hyundai and works ok.
I get something like this

> PART 1
>
> car hyundai
>
> PART 2
>
> car toyota

but if I want to change part 2 from toyota to hyundai won't get replace on part 2, it will replace my part1.. getting something like this:

> PART 1
>
> car hyundai
>
> PART 2
>
> car toyota

I want part 2 to make it work as part 1 does... what's wrong with my code?

this is my html:

```
<form method="post" class="" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="car1">CAR 1: </label>
    <input id="car1" class="form-control" type="text" name="car_1" value="{{ car }}">
    <br>
    <label for="car2">CAR 2: </label>
    <input id="car2" class="form-control" type="text" name="car_2" value="{{ car2 }}">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="car" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Save">
</form>
```

hope you could help me.

I'll apreciate your help a lot.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that `replace` will replace only first N occurrences in string. If you need to replace second occurrence you can implement custom method, something like this:

```
def replace_second_car(filedata, old_car, new_car):
     places = [i.start() for i in re.finditer('car\s(.*?)\s',filedata)]
     start_place = places[1]
     return filedata[:start_place] + filedata[start_place:].replace(old_car, new_car)
```

now in view you can use it like this:

```
filedata = replace_second_car(filedata, car2, change_car_2)
```

Comment: OP returns car[1] in car_p2() therefore only one occurrence. OP's replace functionality works properly

Comment: @HaifengZhang OP initial files include two same rows: `car toyota`. He try to replace only second of them.

Comment: car_p1() returns toyota in PART1 area, car_p2() returns toyota in PART2 area

Comment: @HaifengZhang this is true, but when he do `replace(car2, 'honda') this replaced only first toyota. Because car=car2='toyota'.

Comment: didnt notcie OP read the whole file as one string , +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

As [neverwalkaloner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641249/neverwalkaloner) mentioned, you always replace the 1st occurrence when you read the whole file into one string `filedata`. it would be fine if `toyota` appears only once but would fail when more than once.

You can replace the `filedata` string from right-to-left for car2.

Change `filedata=filedata.replace(car2 , change_car_2 , 1)` to `filedata=change_car_2.join(filedata.rsplit(car2, 1))`